# How to implement Kubernetes operator event load-balancing?

Tags: kubernetes-operator, operator-sdk

I am building an operator using the operator-sdk (https://sdk.operatorframework.io/) which reconciles a specific crd.

I would like the be able to deploy the operator with "load balancing" between the different replicas. For example, if I have 3 events on 3 different object of the relevant crd type, 2 of these vents will be reconciled with instance "1" and the others will be reconciled with the instance "2".

The closest thing I have been able to find is the 'MaxConcurrentReconciles' option (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/pkg/controller?utm_source=godoc#Options) which allows for something similar, but at the process level.

What it the right way to implement this feature in a generic way?